# Definition sum over $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_{nm}\}_{n,m\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. I know that $$ \sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty}a_{nm} $$ is defined as $$\lim_{N,M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{m=0}^Ma_{nm}, $$ where $\lim_{N,M\rightarrow\infty}$ expresses the limit of a double sequence.

How does one define $$ \sum_{n,m=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{nm} \,?$$

Comment: You would need to find a bijection $\mathbb{N} \leftrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. You can take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum is just:

$$\sum_{(n,m) \in \Bbb Z^2} f(n,m)$$

Where $f(x,y) = a_{xy}$.

- If $A$ is a countable set (i.e. a set in bijection with $\Bbb N$), provided that we know a bijection $g: A \to \Bbb N$, we define (provided we have convergence) for $f: A \to \Bbb C$:

$$\sum_{x \in A} f(x) = \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} f(g^{-1}(n))$$

If we know a bijection $g: \Bbb N \to A$, then we can also write:

$$\sum_{x \in A} f(x) = \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} f(g(n))$$

- Most generally: let $A$ be any set. Let $m$ be the counting measure on $A$. We define, for $f\in L^1(A, \Bbb C)$,

$$\sum_{x \in A}f(x) = \int_A f dm$$